# Drools 8.x Java 8 Compatibility

Tags: java, spring, drools

I'm considering using Drools to create and manage business rules in my application.
The documentation (https://docs.drools.org/8.32.0.Final/drools-docs/docs-website/drools/getting-started/index.html) mentions JDK 11+ as a prerequisite.
My application is Spring Boot 2.x that uses Java 8. Upgrading my application to Java 11 is not an option. Is Drools 8.x compatible with Java 8? If not, is there a matrix of Drools and Java version?

Comment: Spring Boot 2.x works on Java 11 and higher as well (at least recent Spring Boot 2.x versions like Spring Boot 2.7), upgrading should hardly be an issue.

Comment: What was your decision?  Did you go with Drools?  If so, what version did you choose that is compatible with Java 8?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct, for Drools 8, Java 11 is min version required.

We noted that as well [in the release notes](https://www.drools.org/docs/drools/release-notes/index.html#_minimum_requirements_update) too:

> JDK 11 is now the minimum Java version required to ***compile*** Drools and [JRE 11 to] ***make use of*** Drools.

As well as other prerequisite updates.

Comment: It turns out that Drools 7.73.0 requires Java 11 also even though the documentation states otherwise.   https://groups.google.com/g/drools-usage/c/NBjkebQUPTM/m/vCQkDVVuAgAJ

Comment: Drools 7.x works just fine with Java 1.8. See https://groups.google.com/g/drools-usage/c/NBjkebQUPTM/m/kQiTlZyuAAAJ

Comment: I must be picking up a Drools 8 binary somehow.  Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 1):

Technically the JDK and the JRE are two different components, but any reasonable distribution of JDK 11 would be built with Java 11's class version, so JRE 8 won't be able to use it.

**EDIT:**
Actually, Drools 8.x JARs are compiled with Java 11 too, so using Java 8 would be a no-go right off the bat.